# Trying to start Activity with PendingIntent from Service and doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sensors

I'm trying to start an Activity from a background service when a condition is meet, I'm checking the logs and it does work because the condition is working, the problem is that the Activity is not launch.

I'm launching the `Activity` as follows

```
val intent = Intent(this@MyService.applicationContext, Activity2::class.java).apply {
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                }
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
                try {
                    pendingIntent.send()
                } catch (e: CanceledException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
```

The thing is if I meet the condition just before the service starts it works, but if I go to another app and start using it, the activity doesn't get launch.

Looking to the [background-starts documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) I've opted to do the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` option where I ask for permissions

```
private fun checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
            startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }
```

Then on my `Service` it overlays and create a button so when I click it starts the activity but the problem it only happens when the power is connected, otherwise looks like Android kills the Service and can not launch the Activity because of Battery Optimization is there any way where I can whitelist this app to don't kill services for a X period of time?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Restrictions of starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes I did, sorry I updated my question I forgot to mention something, take a look please